# How an Android phone interacts with the server?

Tags: android, localhost, android-ksoap2, android-networking

I have an app running fine in emulator but not in mobile. That is app basically fetch some records from server using webservice.(SOAP). Installation is successfull and i can open the first page.but not able to proceed further due to server communication. I need your help in making this app to work fine in my android phone too. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Someone downvoted your question, I will upvote you again.

Comment: Please provide some code, it could be that your application is using the Main Thread, where Network Connections are not allowed.

Comment: @Erdinc Ay, thank you :P And the problem was all with the IP address.. As  Zygotelnit recommended, I changed it and its Working like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be accessing the web service on your local network (localhost). An emulator can access a localhost web service, but a real device cannot. To test the app on an actual device, you need to expose your web service through a public IP address (public URL).

Comment: `To test the app on an actual device, you need to expose your web service through a public IP address (public URL).`. No. If wifi is used and both sides are in the same network a local ip address will do.

Comment: By `local network` I meant a `localhost`. The OP understood what I meant, as any seasoned web developer would. Wifi does not provide connectivity through a localhost IP address, did you ever think of that ? Please clarify your own concepts before you launch into a tirade.